# Background image cover on Android browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, background

I am using an 1900X1200 Image as a background of my page:

```
                  body{
                  background: url(Layout/Ball7.png);
                  background-position: center center;
                  background-repeat:no-repeat;
                 -webkit-background-size: cover;
                 -moz-background-size: cover;
                 -o-background-size: cover;
                  background-size: cover;}
```

It covers the whole screen on both Desktop version and iOs Safari versions.
Thing is, on android native browser (I've tried on three different devices) it leaves a blank white area on the top and bottom of the screen(approx. 15% blank from top and bottom).
If I delete the `background-position: center center;`, the top of the screen will also be a part of the background, but still there will be a blank white in the bottom of the page(apprx.15%). I have also tried to use this code as a solution:

```
height:100%   width: 100%;
height: 100%;  
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;
```

But without any luck, the bottom part of screen is not covered. Am I missing anything here? I have tried many options but none fit exactly my needs.

Possible solution: I have tried to use a very large Image(1900x2500), and it does cover the whole screen but this solution is a last resort, I would like to stick to my 1900x1200 image.

Thanks for any light on that matter.

Answer (score -2):

```
body {
    background: url(Layout/Ball7.png) no-repeat top left fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't set any background, only when I change the first html tag to the body tag.

Comment: I've just edit my old answer. This works to me on Chrome on Nexus 5

Comment: Thanks for the reply, using your code on an android native browser, there is still a blank white area on the bottom of the screen(15% out of the whole screen). Thanks for any further light on that matter.

Comment: At least one sentence explaining your answer would be great.